# How to use one model file for two different CodeIgniter projects

Tags: model-view-controller, codeigniter-2, models

I have two CodeIgniter projects say A and B. Now there are some models files in the A which I want to use it again in B Controllers directly. IS there any way how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to directly access a model inside another application. But if you want you can get the same behavior by a curl request.

Here is the logic,

**Application A**

in your controller A, you have to create 2 functions, function A and B. Both calls to Model A.
Function A is for your normal use(Inside application). 
In Function B what you do is get the result and echo the result in JSON format.

**Application B**

In this controller, what you do is use CURL request to get the result which was echo by app A--> controller A --> function B

Read more about CURL and you will find your solution.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable reply. I am unable to find any answer regarding this. It is very helpful if you can elaborate it little more. I know how to use curl but my problem is that I don't want to load my database two times for the similar task. could you please explain it with little code

Comment: Yeah.. I can support you with code,but before can you explain what you want to achieve. What is the logic behind it. I know that you want to access a model from another app. but if you can be more specific, I can help.

Comment: Hi, I have one website and one app for the same task but for both, I have two different CodeIgniter project as their backend. Means two model for the same task. Now I want to add only one model in the website CodeIgniter project for that operation which performs on both like user registration login and etc functionality.